# Https connection refused, using ingress-nginx

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, https, kubernetes-ingress

I've kubernetes installed on Ubuntu 19.10.
I've setup ingress-nginx and can access my test service using http.
However, I get a "Connection refused" when I try to access via https.

[Edit] I'm trying to get https to terminate in the ingress and pass unencrypted traffic to my service the same way http does. I've implemented the below based on many examples I've seen but with little luck.

Yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: messagemanager-service
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: messagemanager-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: messagemanager
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 31212
    name: http

  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.0.210


---
kind: Deployment
#apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: messagemanager
  labels:
        app: messagemanager
        version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: messagemanager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: messagemanager
        version: v1
    spec:  
      containers:
      - name: messagemanager
        image: test/messagemanager:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: messagemanager-ingress
  annotations: 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: false
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-secret  
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /message
          backend:
            serviceName: messagemanager-service
            servicePort: 8080
```

https test

```
curl -kL https://192.168.0.210/message -verbose
*   Trying 192.168.0.210:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 192.168.0.210 port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 192.168.0.210 port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.210 port 443: Connection refused
```

http test

```
curl -kL http://192.168.0.210/message -verbose
*   Trying 192.168.0.210:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.0.210 (192.168.0.210) port 80 (#0)
> GET /message HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.0.210
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> Referer: rbose
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Date: Fri, 24 Apr 2020 18:44:07 GMT
< connection: keep-alive
< content-length: 50
<
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.0.210 left intact
```

```
$ kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.105.92.236   <pending>     80:31752/TCP,443:32035/TCP   2d
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.100.223.87   <none>        443/TCP                      2d

$ kubectl get ingress -o wide
NAME                     CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
messagemanager-ingress   <none>   *                 80, 443   37m
```

key creation

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=nginxsvc/O=nginxsvc"
kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --key tls.key --cert tls.crt
```

```
$ kubectl describe ingress
Name:             messagemanager-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  tls-secret terminates
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /message   messagemanager-service:8080 ()
Annotations:  Events:
  Type        Reason  Age   From                      Message
  ----        ------  ----  ----                      -------
  Normal      CREATE  107s  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/messagemanager-ingress
```

I was under the assumption that TLS would terminate in the ingress and the request would be passed on to the service as http.
I had to add the external IPs in the service to get HTTP to work.
Am I missing something similar for HTTPS?

Any help and guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes Nginx Ingress can connect to https pods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382853/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-can-connect-to-https-pods)

Comment: Thanks. No this refers to SSL pass through. I want the SSL to terminate in the ingress.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've reproduced your scenario in my lab and after a few changes in your ingress it's working as you described.

In my lab I used an nginx image that serves a default landing page on port 80 and with this Ingress rule, it's possible to serve it on port 80 and 443.

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
        app: nginx
        version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        version: v1
    spec:  
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31000
    name: http          
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx  
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /  
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-secret  
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx-service
          servicePort: 80
```

The only difference between my ingress and yours is that I removed `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: false`. In the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#ssl-passthrough) we can read:

> note SSL Passthrough is **disabled by default**

So there is no need for you to specify that.

I used the same secret as you:

```
$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=nginxsvc/O=nginxsvc"
$ kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --key tls.key --cert tls.crt
```

In your question I have the impression that you are trying to reach your ingress through the IP `192.168.0.210`. This is your service IP and not your Ingress IP.

If you are using Cloud managed Kubernetes you have to run the following command to find your Ingress IP:

```
$ kubectl get ingresses nginx 
NAME    HOSTS   ADDRESS        PORTS     AGE
nginx   *       34.89.108.48   80, 443   6m32s
```

If you are running on Bare Metal without any LoadBalancer solution as [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/), you can see that your ingress-nginx service will be with `EXTERNAL-IP` on `Pending` forever.

```
$ kubectl get service -n ingress-nginx 
NAME                                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-1587980954-controller             LoadBalancer   10.110.188.236   <pending>     80:31024/TCP,443:30039/TCP   23s
```

You can do the same thing as you did with your service and add an externalIP manually:

```
 kubectl get service -n ingress-nginx 
NAME                                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-1587980954-controller             LoadBalancer   10.110.188.236   10.156.0.24   80:31024/TCP,443:30039/TCP   9m14s
```

After this change, your ingress will have the same IP as you defined in your Ingress Service:

```
$ kubectl get ingress nginx 
NAME    CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS       PORTS     AGE
nginx   <none>   *       10.156.0.24   80, 443   118s
```

```
$ curl -kL https://10.156.0.24/nginx --verbose
*   Trying 10.156.0.24...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.156.0.24 (10.156.0.24) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  start date: Apr 27 09:49:19 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 27 09:49:19 2021 GMT
*  issuer: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x560cee14fe90)
> GET /nginx HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.156.0.24
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< server: nginx/1.17.10
< date: Mon, 27 Apr 2020 10:01:29 GMT
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 612
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< last-modified: Tue, 14 Apr 2020 14:19:26 GMT
< etag: "5e95c66e-264"
< accept-ranges: bytes
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 10.156.0.24 left intact
```

EDIT:

> There does not seem to be a way to manually set the "external IPs" for
> the ingress as can be done in the service. If you know of one please
> let me know :-). Looks like my best bet is to try MetalLB.

MetalLB would be the best option for production. If you are running it for lab only, you have the option to add your node public IP (the same you can get by running `kubectl get nodes -o wide`) and attach it to your NGINX ingress controller.

**Adding your node IP to your NGINX ingress controller**

```
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.0.210
```

Create a file called  `ingress-nginx-svc-patch.yaml`  and paste the contents above.

Next apply the changes with the following command:

```
kubectl patch service ingress-nginx-controller -n kube-system --patch "$(cat ingress-nginx-svc-patch.yaml)"
```

And as result:

```
$ kubectl get service -n kube-system ingress-nginx-controller
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller   LoadBalancer   10.97.0.243   192.168.0.210   80:31409/TCP,443:30341/TCP   39m
```

Comment: Thanks for this. So the ingress was never being hit by the requests, it was always the service via the external IP. That makes sense and explains the connection refused error for https. There does not seem to be a way to manually set the "external IPs" for the ingress as can be done in the service. If you know of one please let me know :-). Looks like my best bet is to try MetalLB.

Comment: I edited my answer including something related to your question. Let me know if you have any other question. If my answer helped your, please don't forget to [accept and upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: MetaLB installed and working as expected. Very easy and quick install. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Enjoy your Ingress.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but any time I've seen a service handle http, and https traffic, it's specified two ports in the svc yaml, one for http and one for https. Apparently there are ways to get around this, reading [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/47876/handling-http-and-https-requests-using-a-single-port-with-nginx) might be a good start.

For two ports, look at the official k8s example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/https-nginx/nginx-app.yaml)

Comment: Thanks. The two ports is TLS pass though from what I can gather. If I add the port 443 in the service I get an incorrect TLS version. I believe this means that the service is not handling https which is correct. I want to have https terminated in the ingress and passed to the service as http. From the examples I've seen this should work..... I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same situation for a while and was about to start using metalLB but realised after running `kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc` the ingress-nginx had created its own nodePort and i could access the cluster through that.

Im not an expert but its probably not good for production but i don't see why not.